# Issue with SWT Modal dialog when using SWT-AWT bridge in Linux

Tags: linux, gtk, eclipse-rcp, awt, swt-awt

We have developed a RCP product with OSIG Plugin. Every thing is working fine in windows. But the problem is with Linux(GTK)
We used Code:

```
Composite composite = new Composite(parent, SWT.EMBEDDED | SWT.NO_BACKGROUND | SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL); 
frame = swt_awt.new_frame(composite);
```

When we open any SWT modal dialog, this frame is not blocked. Other than this frame other SWT area got blocked and are not accessible. I hope its internal implementation. Can any one give some suggestion whether is there any work around. I am trying since 2 weeks. please help me

**Eclipse:** `eclipse-jee-indigo-SR2-win32` **OS :** `RHEL 6`

Comment: how come your OS is `RHEL 6` and your development IDE is `eclipse-jee-indigo-SR2-win32` (its for windows) ??

Comment: Its eclipse-SDK-3.7-linux-gtk.tar.gz I mean that I am using 3.7, any have problem got resolved and we find workaround by setting frame setEnabled(false)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it's probably an Eclipse bug - the SWT_AWT bridge is historically a rather buggy area, especially on non-Windows platforms. Check [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/buglist.cgi?short_desc=SWT_AWT&resolution=---&resolution=WONTFIX&resolution=NOT_ECLIPSE&query_format=advanced&bug_status=UNCONFIRMED&bug_status=NEW&bug_status=ASSIGNED&bug_status=REOPENED&bug_status=RESOLVED&bug_status=VERIFIED&bug_status=CLOSED&short_desc_type=allwordssubstr) for the set of open SWT_AWT bugs to see if yours is already entered (or won't be fixed).